# How to plot multiple lines according to values of lists on the same axis, on pysimplegui, on python

Tags: python, plot, pysimplegui

I have a project where I find the heart rate of an user and have to plot it on a graph against the target zone's which I find according to another heart rate.

I got this code for plotting a list of values on a line graph off of the pysimplegui demo's, however I am strugguling to plot three different lists at once.

The lists I need to plot are the following:
ListHR
PlotMax (straight line)
PlotMin (straight line)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import execute_py_file
import json
import datetime

plotMin = [123]*60
plotMax = [200]*60
listBPM = [65,67,70,72,80,85,90,95,110,115,130]

BAR_WIDTH = 10
# BAR_WIDTH = 5
BAR_SPACING = 16
# BAR_SPACING = 6
EDGE_OFFSET = 3
GRAPH_SIZE = (550,500)
DATA_SIZE = (500,200)
graph = sg.Graph(GRAPH_SIZE, (0,-30), DATA_SIZE, background_color='white',)

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color

layout = [[sg.Text('chart demo')],
          [graph],
          [sg.Button('OK')]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

before_value = 0
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    graph.Erase()
    if event is None:
        break
    for i in range(0,len(listBPM)-1): # have to find out how to plot three different lines
        graph_value = listBPM[i+1] #variable not changing... 
        if i > 0:
            graph.DrawLine(((i-1) * BAR_SPACING + EDGE_OFFSET+ BAR_WIDTH/2 ,  before_value)  ,  (i * BAR_SPACING + EDGE_OFFSET+ BAR_WIDTH/2 , graph_value ),color='blue', width=1 )

        graph.DrawText(text=graph_value, location=(i*BAR_SPACING+EDGE_OFFSET+2, graph_value+10))

        graph.DrawPoint((i * BAR_SPACING + EDGE_OFFSET+ BAR_WIDTH/2 ,graph_value), size=3 ,color='blue',)
        before_value = graph_value

window.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a figure, something maybe concerned,

- Generate all points by a convert function
- Find the range of x and y to confirm what view for the figure
- To draw joined lines or trace, you can call method `draw_lines` of `sg.Graph`

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_point(i, y):
    return (i * BAR_SPACING + EDGE_OFFSET + BAR_WIDTH/2, y)

listBPM = [65,67,70,72,80,85,90,95,110,115,130]
plotMin = [123]*len(listBPM)
plotMax = [200]*len(listBPM)

BAR_WIDTH   = 10
BAR_SPACING = 16
EDGE_OFFSET = 3
GRAPH_SIZE  = (550,500)

# Generate all data points
lines = [
    [new_point(i, y) for i, y in enumerate(listBPM)],
    [new_point(i, y) for i, y in enumerate(plotMin)],
    [new_point(i, y) for i, y in enumerate(plotMax)],
]
sg.theme('DarkAmber')

# Find the range for data
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = 10000, 10000, 0, 0
for line in lines:
    for x, y in line:
        min_x, min_y = min(min_x, x), min(min_y, y)
        max_x, max_y = max(max_x, x), max(max_y, y)

graph = sg.Graph(
    GRAPH_SIZE,
    (min_x - EDGE_OFFSET - BAR_WIDTH/2, min_y - EDGE_OFFSET - BAR_WIDTH/2),
    (max_x + EDGE_OFFSET + BAR_WIDTH/2, max_y + EDGE_OFFSET + BAR_WIDTH/2),
    background_color='white')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('chart demo'), sg.Button('OK')],
    [graph],
]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event is None:
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        graph.erase()
        for line in lines:
            graph.draw_lines(line, color='blue', width=1)
        for x, y in lines[0]:
            graph.draw_text(text=y, location=(x, y+10))
            graph.draw_point((x, y), size=3 ,color='blue')

window.Close()
```

[image]